# How to calculate subspace of a set of solutions of matrix Ax=b

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, invariant-subspace

I am looking through some old linear algebra exam papers. However i do not understand how to calculate whether a set of solutions is within a certain subspace R. This is the problem in question:

[image]

I think i understand how to check whether vectors are within a subspace R, but how would i calculate this?

Thanks a lot, really hope you can help me out!

Comment: What is $\mathcal{R}$?

Comment: What have you tried? What is your understanding of how to determine if a set is a subspace of the vector space $\mathbb{R} $?

Comment: I tried to follow this video:

Comment: I tried to follow this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q97HmMdD8ZM

And to me it seems that the subspace is equal to the amount of rows of the vectors within the span. Am i completely off track or?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you want to calculate?

Comment: "Calculate" was probably the wrong word for me to use. I'd like to know why it is exactly 4 in R^4? If B had been the null vector, and the set of solutions are the subspace, would it then have to be 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of solutions of $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ is not a subespace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ becasuse the null vector $\mathbf{0}=\begin{bmatrix}{0}\\{0}\\{0}\\{0}\end{bmatrix}$ does not satisfy $A\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{b}$.

Comment: Thank you. Is this the same as saying that it is because the last row does not equal the zero vector?

Comment: - Of the RREF of Ax=B, i mean. Sorry i do not understand how to edit my comments.

Comment: No, nothing to do. For example, $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ would be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ with $A$ the same matrix.

Comment: @user102937 No, it’s the same as saying that $\mathbf b\ne\mathbf 0$. The solution set to $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$ can only be a vector space when $\mathbf b=\mathbf 0$. The rref in the problem is sort of a red herring.

Comment: Thanks again Alone and amd. So just to be completely sure i get it: If and only if b=0, can said problem be true? And if b=0 is it then always within the subspace R^n?

Comment: @user102937 : Right.